# Session management in Spring with REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, session

So I am building a REST-API using Spring for a simple game. I now have the need to be able to track a user together with some data (what games they're in and on what team). I got some tips that Spring security might be worth checking out, however I fail to see how that would help me without necessitating a login.

Are there any good methods for doing this?

I've also tried using the session which can be gotten from HttpServletRequest, however this session differs from the first navigation to the webpage, which I was not able to resolve and I'm worried that it would be too unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

REST is supposed to be stateless. That means you don't really want to have a session for stuff like user data. This should all be persisted server side and managed via rest calls. You would have a User resource and a Game resource and perhaps a relation between them, all held in a database. Spring Security is not going to help you with any of this.

What Spring Security might be able to help you with is securing your REST services and managing identity. Although REST is stateless, it is normal for a client to send something like an access token in a HTTP header. This access token provides both identity and authentication. Again, you will need to separately manage and store the relationship between the access token and the user server side, perhaps in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Session can be fetched from HttpSession and not HTTPServeletRequest. HttpSessions are reliable.